# What is the right way to add google sign-in in Expo React Native that works on Android Standalone app?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo, google-signin

I tried these three packages provided by EXPO and neither of them is working :

1. [GoogleSignIn](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/) : This is marked deprecated, does not work in expo go or web so that we can debug, only works when .apk is built which makes it unreliable.
2. [GoogleAppAuth](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/google/) : Again, deprecated. Works in expo go but does not work in Android Native.
3. [AuthSession](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#google) : This is the recommended package by expo but it has this [open](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12044) issue which makes it unusable for android application.

Google Sign in is quite easy with other frameworks or even web. It is too tedious here in react native and I already wasted a lot of time. Please advise what am I missing here or if you have a  solution?

Comment: I am experiencing the same exact issue on the Android Standalone app using Expo. I've spent months at a complete dead stop trying to get the Google login working on Android. I've tried these exact same packages, and cannot get them working.

The point of using React Native is to be able to write an app for both IOS and Android at the same time. Not being able to login with Oauth is a complete show stopper.

Following and hope that someone can help find an answer.